# view.onclicklistener cannot be implemented

Tags: android, debugging, button, onclicklistener

I am new with android studio, I tried to do a test like, push two different button show different text in Textview.
 And my .java code is

```
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
 import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
 import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
 import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.view.Menu;
 import android.view.MenuItem;
 import android.widget.TextView;
 import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
  public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        TextView t1;
        t1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.editText);

        t1.setOnClickListener(this);
    }
   @Override
    public void onClick (View v) {
       if (v.getId() == R.id.button)
           t1.setText("Customer1");
       if (v.getId() == R.id.button2)
           t1.setText("Custom2");
       }
   }
```

Symbol 't1' cannot be resolved in

```
 t1.setText("Customer1");

 import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
```

shows unused import statement.
I want to know which part is wrong with code, and how to fix it.

Thx

Comment: see below answer .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have written the onClickLister method however you have not implemented the interface.

Try changing this

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
```

To This

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener
```

And implement `onClick(View v)` method in the class in place of your `onClickListener`

Regarding the t1 issue. The reson you are getting the error is because you declare t1 as a local variable. Move t1 so its a global variable and that should solve the issue. Like this

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{

public TextView t1;

@Override
protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    t1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.editText);
    t1.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick (View v) {
   if (v.getId() == R.id.button)
       t1.setText("Customer1");
   if (v.getId() == R.id.button2)
       t1.setText("Custom2");
   }
```

}

Comment: Thanks a lot. But still cannot resolve symbol 't1' in     t1.setText("Custom2");    i alreday change my code

Comment: @Albert Ive changed my answer to include this

Comment: No problem @Albert. Feel free to check my response as the answer

Answer (score 1):

Implement OnClickListener

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener
```

set listener to your view`t1.setOnClickListener(this);`

and add your code to onClick()

```
 @Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if (v.getId() == R.id.button)
        t1.setText("Customer1");
    if (v.getId() == R.id.button2)
        t1.setText("Custom2");
}
```

Comment: Thanks, OnClickListener is implemented but still cannot resolve symbol 't1'  in        t1.setText("Custom2");

Comment: Declare t1 at Class level (outside onCreate() )

Answer (score 0):

Use either one approach.

Either implement the interface

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements{

    TextView t1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        t1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.editText);

        t1.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    //its onClick -> Not OnClickListener
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch(v.getId()){
                    case R.id.button:
                        t1.setText("Customer1");
                        break;
                    case R.id.button2:
                        t1.setText("Custom2");
                        break;
                }
    }
}
```

or create a View.OnClickListener object

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView t1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        t1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.editText);

        View.OnClickListener onclickListnere = new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                switch(v.getId()){
                    case R.id.button:
                        t1.setText("Customer1");
                        break;
                    case R.id.button2:
                        t1.setText("Custom2");
                        break;
                }
            }
        };

        t1.setOnClickListener(onclickListnere);
    }
}
```

**Update :**

Declare TextView t1 as class member variable. You declared it as a local variable and hence not available in the onClick Method